# What is an alternative to the scan() function in R which is not just for files

Tags: r, split, delimiter

I have to read a list of text files starting with the name hello that are located in the same folder. I have to remove period after each letter because I only want to only use period as delimiters.

For example, if a line of text looks like this one : “apple. 10.”

I erase the period on the same line to get this result: “apple 10.”

Here is a glimpse of my code.

```
 files0 <- list.files(path=maindir,pattern="hello",full.names=F,recursive=T,
 include.dirs=T)
```

The next loop is not very efficient, because I have to create temporary text files to use the scan() function.

```
 ############### First step

for(a in 1:length(files0)){ #start of the loop going through 
# every files0

        read <- readLines(paste(maindir,files0[a],sep="/")) #read each line

        hello <- gsub("(\\D+)\\.","\\1", lec) #remove every period after a letter

        write.table(mod,file=paste(maindir,paste("temporary",files0[a],sep="_"),sep="/"),
        sep =     ";",col.names = T,row.names = F,quote = FALSE) 
        #create new temporary files without the period  after a letter

} #end of the loop

 ##################Second step

   files <- list.files(path=maindir,pattern="temporary",full.names=F,
   recursive=T,include.dirs=T)

   for(b in 1:length(files)){ #start of the loop going through every files

           hola <- scan(files[b],character(), sep=".") #read every files and 
           # use period as delimiters
   } #end of the loop
```

I would like to find an alternative to the scan() function in R since I would not have to create temporary files. Also, I would want to be able to directly use the original files (files0) without modifying them.

For example, I have tried the strsplit() function but it didn't properly delimite my text file using a period.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can give a representative example of the text in the files I'm sure somebody could come up with quick `strsplit` regex to get your result without double-handling each file.

Comment: What file types are you reading? And you can try to vectorize it with map()

Comment: data.frame of all of your files with hello. 
files0 <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern="hello",
                     full.names=F,
                     recursive=T,
                     include.dirs=T) %>% 
  tbl_df()

Vectorize the file reading with map (I use data.tabe::fread as I found it the most efficient). 
files0 %>% 
  mutate(hola  = map(value, ~data.table::fread(.)))

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative.

```
for(a in 1:length(files0)){ #start of the loop going through 
# every files0

    read <- readLines(paste(maindir,files0[a],sep="/")) #read each line

    hello <- gsub("(\\D+)\\.","\\1", lec) #remove every period after a letter

hello1 <- unlist(strsplit(hello, "[.]"))

} #end of the loop
```

I simply have to use the functions unlist(strsplit()).